# mcustomscrollbar "scrollTo" does not work in chrome, but the same code works in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

mcustomscrollbar "scrollTo" does not work in chrome, but the same code works in FireFox.
I don't get any errors in console. It looks like a per browser issue. I also checked functionality on - http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollTo_demo.html and faced with the same problem in Chrome only with vertical scroll.

```
$('body.Office .use-custom-scrollbar').useCustomScrollbar();
                var scrollToElement = $('.day.today').length ? $('.day.today') : $('.day.future:first');
                scrollToElement = scrollToElement.length ? scrollToElement.closest(".one-day-container") : $(".one-day-container:last");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('body.Office .use-custom-scrollbar').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", scrollToElement);
                }, 0);
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about "does not work"?  Do you get an error message in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After entire day of searching solution I have come up with such answer:

- http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollTo_demo.html - for this site I just removed *overflow: hidden* property for *.mCSB_container* selector:

```
.mCSB_container {
 overflow: unset !important;
}
```

- Unfortunately, the first answer doesn't solve problem with my code, so I disabled *scrollInertia* property for *mCustomScrollbar* to avoid this issue. Now, code looks like this:

```
$('body.Office .use-custom-scrollbar').useCustomScrollbar();

var scrollToElement = $('.day.today').length ? $('.day.today') : $('.day.future:first');
scrollToElement = scrollToElement.length ? scrollToElement.closest(".one-day-container") : $(".one-day-container:last");
setTimeout(function () {
            $('body.Office .use-custom-scrollbar').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", scrollToElement, {
                        scrollInertia: 0
              });
}, 0);
```